# Session_OnStart() does not fire on the first GET request

Tags: c#, asp.net, sessionid

I have a weird problem. Can't explain this inconsistent behavior.

Normally I would expect that the first `GET` request to load my `default.aspx` to fire the `Session_OnStart()` event. However, this happens only on the first page load after restarting the IIS. On all subsequent page loads (after clearing cookies), `Session_OnStart()` does not fire on the first `GET` request.

The page also makes two other `POST` requests from the client side through jQuery Ajax. `Session_OnStart()` does fire for BOTH of these requests on all subsequent page loads (again after clearing cookies).

This is a problem because `SessionId` is not being set on the first response, rather its being set twice on the subsequent responses to the `POST` requests. So the application ends up creating two `SessionIds` for each user. And again this does not happen on the first page load right after the IIS restart, which is the weird part.

it is an asp.net 3.5 website running on IIS 7.

Comment: What does your uri in GET request look like? Doesn't it contain session id in parameters?

Comment: Here is the GET request (removed the domain)
GET http://[domain]/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: [domain]

Comment: Looks like its not only Session_OnStart that is not being fired.  PreRequestHandlerExecute and PostRequestHandlerExecute are also not being fired.